# Unable to restore SharePoint 2016 Project site

Tags: sql-server-2016, ms-project, sharepoint-2016

```
Restore-SPSite : The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "MSP_PROJECT_RESOURCES_RES_TYPE_RULE". The conflict occurred in database "WSS_Content_2221", table 
"pjpub.MSP_PROJECT_RESOURCES".
The statement has been terminated.
At line:1 char:1
+ Restore-SPSite -Identity "http://*****sea01:2221/ " -Path D:\Backup\epmitsi ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...dletRestoreSite:SPCmdletRestoreSite) [Restore-SPSite], SqlException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletRestoreSite
```

Comment: Looks like your insert statement conflicted with the check constraint.

Comment: what is the solution Jacob?